# “everywhere” vs. “anywhere” vs. “somewhere”

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, compounds

Which one is correct to use?

1. We usually stay home because it's more comfortable than go
   everywhere/anywhere/somewhere

Comment: They're all grammatical. However, it's a logical impossibility to go *everywhere* (unless you restrict your scope to a finite area—but even that could get tiring). It's also unlikely that you would go literally *anywhere*. (I'm sure there are some places some people would not like to visit.) However, you could say *anywhere* ***else***. So, *somewhere* seems the most *sensible* single word.

Comment: In a different context "go everywhere" might mean "try every attraction in this amusement park we are visiting" or some such.

Answer (score 1):

All examples are correct grammatically, but '***EVERYWHERE***' sounds strange here ('to all places?').

'***SOMEWHERE***'
('to some place') is better and possible,

but I would use '***ANYWHERE***'

According to *[Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/anywhere)*:

> ***ANYWHERE***
>
> PRONOUN
> Any place.

For example:

> ‘he doesn't have anywhere to live’
>
> ‘Is there anywhere we can go that God doesn’t see?’
>
> ‘I didn't have anywhere to go.’
>
> ‘Is there anywhere I can buy a Mountain Bike online?’

Comment: As far as i know, we use "any" with negative and interrogative sentences. Is it okey to use it with positive sentence?

Comment: In statements 'any' means 'no limit'.

Comment: @MorVor ‘Negative’ is a broad and fuzzy term. In this case, even though there is no explicit negator in the sentence, the comparative construction approaches negativeness just enough that either the negative polarity version (_anywhere_) or the positive version (_somewhere_) can be used with little to no difference in meaning.

Comment: The use of *anywhere* is fine in *your* sentences. Would you say the most natural of the three sentences asked about in the question is "We usually stay home because it's more comfortable than [going] *anywhere*"?

Comment: 1. Strange, 2. and 3. nearly

Comment: the same. Sorry.